# Why does matlab warn to preallocate a variable which is getting reset every loop?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, pre-allocation

There is a cell variable in my program which Matlab warns to preallocate it. The simple form of code is sth like this:

```
for i = 1:2
    a = [];
    a = [a,{'abc'}];
end
```

First I want to know why `a` should be preallocated, since it's getting reset in each loop. Second I don't know how to preallocate it. When I try to do so, Matlab gives me another warning, saying "The variable appears to be preallocated, but preallocation is not recommended here".

I use this code before the loop:

```
a = cell(1,2);
```

To be more specific:

```
for i = 1:2
    a = [];
    if condition1
        a = {'abc'};
    end
    if condition2
        a = [a,{'def'}];
    end
    b = [{'string'},a];
end
```

I want `b` to be a 1x1 cell array if the conditions are not true, so I need to reset `a` to an empty var in each loop.

Update:

I found a way, hinted by Lee's answer, but still doesn't know why. Using `a = [a(:),{'def'}];` instead of `a = [a,{'def'}];` solved the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made `a` a new variable, thus the former `a = cell(1,2)` was never used, which made matlab raised the warning.

You can use sth like

```
a = cell(1,2);
for ii = 1:2
    a{ii} = 'abc';
end
```

or if you really want to change the size of `a`,

```
for ii = 1:2
    a = {'a1'};
    a = [a(:); {'abc'}];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I added in my question, I need 'a' to get empty in the beginning of each loop. So I can't set it to {'a1'}. What else I can do? Thanks again.

Comment: Just replace your `a = []` by `a = {}`